# Prime reciprocals series proof

Tags: divergent-series, distribution-of-primes

I am currently struggling with the proof of the prime reciprocals series divergence.
I've already proved that :

$$\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1-1/p_k} \longrightarrow +\infty$$

Let $n$ be an integer. How to find $K$ such that :

$$\sum_{k=1}^K \frac{1}{p_k} \geq \sum_{k=1}^n \ln\bigg{(}\frac{1}{1-1/p_k}\bigg{)}$$

It's the last step to demonstrate the divergence of this series, but I can't manage to do so. Could you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\log (1 + x) \le x$ for all $x>0$ and $\frac{1}{{1 - \frac{1}{x}}} \le 1 + \frac{2}{x}$ for $x \ge 2$, one has
$$
\frac{1}{2}\log \left( {\prod\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{1 - 1/p_k }}} } \right) = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\log \frac{1}{{1 - 1/p_k }}}  \le \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\log \left( {1 + \frac{2}{{p_k }}} \right)}  \le \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{2}{{p_k }}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{p_k }}} .
$$
But as you have already shown, the left-hand side diverges as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: Thank you ! So the key point was to observe that $\frac{1}{1-1/x} \leq 1 + \frac{2}{x}$ for $x\geq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

$\ln (\frac 1 {1-t})=\ln (1+\frac t {1-t}) \leq \frac t {1-t}$. From this you get divergence of $\sum_k \frac 1 {p_k-1}$. Since $\frac {p_k} {p_k -1} \to 1$ it follows that $\sum_k \frac  1{p_k}$ is also divergent.